# FindByIdAsync function is showing error while returning value in last line

Tags: entity-framework-6

```
public Task<TUser> 
 FindMainUserByIdAsync(string id){
  var user =_context.Users.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
  return Task.Run(() => user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public async Task
 FindMainUserByIdAsync(string id){
 var user = await _context.Users.Where(x=>x.Id.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
 return user as TUser;
 }